# Why my usb mouse stays on after shutdown?

Tags: usb, xubuntu, mouse, shutdown

In my desktop I have 8 usb ports, only the one the mouse is connected remains on after I shutdown the computer. I tried to plug the mouse on another usb port and this time this one remains on after I shutdown the computer, all the others are off. 
If i chose Hibernate instead of Shutdown, all the usb ports are off.
The same problem happens with different distros like: xubuntu, ubuntu, mint, manjaro.

Is this a bug? Can this cause problems to my comoputer?

Answer (score 1):

This is a "problem" of your motherboard supplying power even when computer is shutdown. I had the same with my old one. My keyboard was on all the time, as well as my mouse. No matter if computer was shut down or sleeping.

Comment: If the OP is lucky, he can have an option for this in the BIOS setup. I have one in my Samsung --- never mind that doesn't work ;-). [Let's rejoice in firmware quality...](http://lwn.net/Articles/387609/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is a BIOS feature called USB mouse support (Not sure about the name) , if it is enabled it will provide power to the USB mouse as long as the power cable is connected to the power supply.
but I'm not sure of the name of the feature, play around with you BIOS options you will find it.